# What does 'stable-to-firm' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "stable to firm" mean in this sentence?

> *Asia methanol prices ***stable-to-firm*** on further supply uncertainties. The import prices of methanol in the Asian market were assessed as ***stable-to-firm*** during the week ended 8 August, reflecting higher buy-sell indications amid further uncertainties in the supply situation.*

Comment: What's the source? Google shows no results for this paragraph. I tried to search and include here as the source.

Comment: Thank you. this is from ICIS that is a site analyzing data.

Comment: @StoneyB — And so it was done.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked up [stable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/stable_1) and [firm](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/firm_2) in a dictionary?

The author uses stable-to-firm to indicate a description of the expected stability of prices (meaning how much they are expected to change).

Stable I'd read as "changing very little", firm as "not changing".

So, stable-to-firm would be somewhere in between those.

(Of course, if you read it as "horse-house to company", I understand it's confusing...)